# How do I animate text in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project for school and I want to make my title page look awesome by having animating "Space invaders" (bigger, smaller, bigger, etc...). I've been trying to get it to work but for some reason it just gets stuck.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    textAnimation()
End Sub

Private Sub textAnimation()
    Dim bestSize As Integer = 0
    If bestSize <= 200 Then
        bestSize += 10
    ElseIf bestSize >= 500 Then
        bestSize -= 10
    End If
    Textbox1.Font = New Font("Showcard Gothic", bestSize)

End Sub
```

Comment: You should learn how to track down such problems yourself. Either use a debugger, or just think about it: what happens when `textAnimation` is called? You create a variable called `bestSize`, initialize it with `0`, then add `10`. Every time. So `bestSize` will always be `10` when creating the `Font` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a very easier way! Let me show you:

Declare the integer `bestsize` globally:

```
Public Class Form 1
     Dim bestsize as integer
```

And then add the following:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     textAnimation()
End Sub

Private Sub textAnimation()
     bestsize = bestsize + 2
     If bestsize = 48 then
           Timer1.Stop
     End If
     TextBox1.Font = New Font("Showcard Gothic", bestsize)
End Sub
```

You can set the increment of `bestsize` as per your wish (you want to increase the size very fast or slow). I hope it would help you to cope with your problem!

Or to make it short and less memory consuming, you can directly write the statements written in `textAnimation` Sub in the `Timer1_Tick` Sub:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     bestsize = bestsize + 2
     If bestsize = 48 then
           Timer1.Stop
     End If
     TextBox1.Font = New Font("Showcard Gothic", bestsize)
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP was trying to do, though. Also the test should be >= not =